# Find frequencies of unique values of one vector in a a different vector

Tags: r, count

If I have a vector of observed values X and a vector of reference values Y, how do I use R to find the frequencies of each value of Y in X?

```
# create X and Y
X = c(1,2,4,5,1,4)
Y = 1:6

# desired output
Y  X 
1  2 
2  1
3  0
4  2 
5  1
6  0
```

I know how to find the frequencies of values of X, or what values of Y are in X, but this is proving (emrbarrinsgly) difficult. I apologise if this has been asked before but I am struggling to find similar questions.

I have tried

```
# 'count' in the "plyr" package
count(X , "unique(Y)" )
```

...but this returns:

```
unique.Y. freq
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         1
6         1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We convert the 'X' to `factor` class specifying the `levels` as the `unique` elements of 'Y' (In this case, there are only 6 unique elements.  But, if there are duplicate elements, use `, levels= unique(Y)`).  Get the frequency of 'Y' and transformed 'X' and do the `colSums`.

```
colSums(table(Y,factor(X, levels=Y)))
#  1 2 3 4 5 6 
#  2 1 0 2 1 0
```

Or as @docendodiscmus mentioned, we can apply `table` on the transformed 'X' to get the output (using this example)

```
table(factor(X, levels = Y))
```

---

Or use `xtabs`.  By default, it gives the `sum` of duplicate elements.  Here, we convert the 'Y' to logical vector so that we get automatically the frequency (by doing the `sum`) with `xtabs`.

```
xtabs(as.logical(Y)~factor(X, levels=Y))
```

Comment: Not sure why you need `colSums`? Won't `table(factor(X, levels = Y))` work?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, it should work.  But, I thought it might have a problem in a large vector with dupes.

Comment: Is there an easy generalisation of this to cases where X and Y may differ in lengths?

Comment: @ user3237820 The solution suggested by @docendodiscimus works irrespective of the length of the vectors.